# Android: Weird crash on Activity Launch. To do with XML layout ordering

Tags: android, android-layout

he this has been driving me nutts, and I hope someone can shed some light on it for me.

I have the following XML layout repeated 3 times in my xml file, and everything is fine, until... I add a background image via an `<ImageView>` tag and align said image with the bottom of the SeekBar, I change the @+id's around so imageview has the +. 
Now the weird thing is I can do this to the last layout group but not either of the others. I've included two here for space sake. the latter one works a treat. It will however allow me to place the 2nd one (thats in the first listing below (recordBox) above the seekbar directly, but not above the linearlayout (and i want it above TextView so its at the back), thats when the crashes start. I've also tried taking it off the last one, and putting on this one only, still no joy.

Another thing i just noticed I can also get it to work with the playBackBox having @+id on both the playBackSeek references.

any ideas out there?

```
 <RelativeLayout
       android:id="@+id/recordBox"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@id/intervalBox"
       android:orientation="vertical"
        >
    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:scaleType="fitXY"
      android:src="@drawable/background"    
      android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/recordSeek"
        />    

          <TextView  android:id="@+id/recordHeader"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Record Duration"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"

            />    

           <LinearLayout  android:id="@+id/record2ndBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_below="@id/recordHeader"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/recordHeader"
            >
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/recordValue"
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:text="50"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="number" 
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp" 
                    />    

                <Spinner android:id="@+id/recordType"
                    android:layout_width="140dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
                    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                    /> 
            </LinearLayout>  

          <SeekBar android:id="@id/recordSeek"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:max="100"
               android:progress="50"
               android:layout_below="@id/record2ndBox"
               android:layout_alignLeft="@id/recordHeader"
               android:paddingBottom="20dp"
               android:paddingRight="20dp"
           /> 


    </RelativeLayout> 

   <RelativeLayout
       android:id="@+id/playBackBox"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@id/recordBox"

       android:orientation="vertical"
        >


     <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:scaleType="fitXY"
      android:src="@drawable/background"    
      android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/playBackSeek"
        />


              <TextView  android:id="@+id/playBackHeader"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Play Back Duration"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"

            />    

           <LinearLayout  android:id="@+id/playBack2ndBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_below="@id/playBackHeader"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/playBackHeader"
            >
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/playBackValue"
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:text="50"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="number" 
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp" 
                    />    

                <Spinner android:id="@+id/playBackType"
                    android:layout_width="140dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
                    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                    /> 
            </LinearLayout>  

          <SeekBar android:id="@id/playBackSeek"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:max="100"
               android:progress="50"
               android:layout_below="@id/playBack2ndBox"
               android:layout_alignLeft="@id/playBackHeader"
               android:paddingBottom="20dp"
               android:paddingRight="20dp"
           /> 

    </RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the Error dump.

```
    03-21 17:26:26.934: E/AndroidRuntime(621): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-21 17:26:26.934: E/AndroidRuntime(621): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mediabar.timelapse/com.mediabar.timelapse.TimeLapseCalculator}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Spinner
03-21 17:26:26.934: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
03-21 17:26:26.934: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
03-21 17:26:26.934: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
03-21 17:26:26.934: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
03-21 17:26:26.934: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-21 17:26:26.934: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-21 17:26:26.934: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-21 17:26:26.934: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-21 17:26:26.934: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-21 17:26:26.934: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-21 17:26:26.934: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-21 17:26:26.934: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-21 17:26:26.934: E/AndroidRuntime(621): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Spinner
03-21 17:26:26.934: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at com.mediabar.timelapse.TimeLapseCalculator.onCreate(TimeLapseCalculator.java:154)
03-21 17:26:26.934: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-21 17:26:26.934: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
```

OnCreate as requested

```
   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); //anim is coming in, going out
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_right_in, R.anim.push_left_out);
        setContentView(R.layout.calculator);
        HDDResults = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.HDDResults);
        timeResults = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TimeResults);      
        extraResults = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ExtraResults);  
        HDDResults.setText("HDD:");
        timeResults.setText("time Results Area:");
        extraResults.setText("Extra Results Area:");

        radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.calcBy);
        rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.byInterval);
        rb2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.byRecord);
        rb3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.byPlayBack);
        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        intSeek = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.intervalSeek);
        intSeek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        intTextValue = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.intervalValue);
        intTextValue.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
        intTextValue.addTextChangedListener(this);

        intType=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.intervalType); 
        intType.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        ArrayAdapter<String> intTypelist=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,intTypeItems);
        intTypelist.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        intType.setAdapter(intTypelist); 

        recSeek = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.recordSeek);
        recSeek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        recTextValue = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.recordValue);
        recTextValue.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
        recTextValue.addTextChangedListener(this);

        recType=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.recordType);        
        recType.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        ArrayAdapter<String>    recTypelist=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,recTypeItems);        
        recTypelist.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);   
        recType.setAdapter(recTypelist);    

        playSeek = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.playBackSeek);
        playSeek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        playTextValue = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.playBackValue);
        playTextValue.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
        playTextValue.addTextChangedListener(this);

        playType=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.playBackType);
        playType.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);   
        ArrayAdapter<String>    playTypelist=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,playTypeItems);              
        playTypelist.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);     
        playType.setAdapter(playTypelist);         

    }
```

Comment: can you post your onCreate method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try projects > Clean if you are on eclipse that should fix all that issue. if not restart eclipse. I had a problem like this before someone told me it's the way the xml file builds over its components. It may got mixed up.

Comment: oh my god how riddiculus, I@ve just spent the best part of an hour on this. yes PROJECT>CLEAN did the trick. I did earlier try restart Eclipse but as that failed I came here and spend 10mins filling out a questions. lol. thanks very much, will have project>clean on a shortcut I think